# Amazon: How to send SNS with cloudformation output data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I want to send a notification with the data output from my cloudformation stack after it has completed using a lambda function that sends the data to Slack.

How can I access the cloudformation output data from the SNS message?

Comment: You can't get outputs from SNS message. You have to get the stack name/arn and use AWS SDK to query the stack for the outputs.

Comment: How do i get the stack arn?? can I get it inside the lambda? because I create new stacks all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SNS message that CloudFormation produces has the following form:

```
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "EventSource": "aws:sns",
            "EventVersion": "1.0",
            "EventSubscriptionArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:761323155761:my-topic:6eaf0af0-8707-45b8-a7fb-c900c56e0ca0",
            "Sns": {
                "Type": "Notification",
                "MessageId": "a681c82f-9a58-58a2-bc5a-9fc379857c94",
                "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:761323155761:my-topic",
                "Subject": "AWS CloudFormation Notification",
                "Message": "StackId='arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:761323155761:stack/fggg/1294f6d0-0225-11eb-93fc-127c6c2d7f71'\nTimestamp='2020-09-29T07:26:21.471Z'\nEventId='129740c0-0225-11eb-93fc-127c6c2d7f71'\nLogicalResourceId='fggg'\nNamespace='761323155761'\nPhysicalResourceId='arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:761323155761:stack/fggg/1294f6d0-0225-11eb-93fc-127c6c2d7f71'\nPrincipalId='AIDA3CQTFOEYUR5EGW2C5'\nResourceProperties='null'\nResourceStatus='CREATE_IN_PROGRESS'\nResourceStatusReason='User Initiated'\nResourceType='AWS::CloudFormation::Stack'\nStackName='fggg'\nClientRequestToken='Console-CreateStack-5414c3bd-914a-5eec-7b6e-1b0e9139cd20'\n",
                "Timestamp": "2020-09-29T07:26:21.560Z",
                "SignatureVersion": "1",
                "Signature": "pE/h7Euukmm4xD/xedKlqN6pFDmWifx5GxdPHnK1pB+RVZvY60rO2XUBYTB11LNbDhaSxt7z6yyOWBHd29bMRtAeOOpl4wHzi3gYbrZbA//8xCdmoRHS2BRq4HMpT8WTxr6/i1dCrIjjyeT5KRGBZ/7WxvKJBixtHt+hjy9u41KUOL2HeHriiE+HYyqMCpzLb9DLY13jwpjtuwlk+e5le5rFmW6SobFLodhWDfers9wH760A5j3CxFt8uQnZmkInpega+SD3rqU9Ue/ZZAxxe2XDMsWT6EgznEJF/ToTbTo6HtNmiXE5iNd5xZAEjfPLPQ1Bc3R+JuvuWuiqJXkzCg==",
                "SigningCertUrl": "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-a86cb10b4e1f29c941702d737128f7b6.pem",
                "UnsubscribeUrl": "https://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:761323155761:my-topic:6eaf0af0-8707-45b8-a7fb-c900c56e0ca0",
                "MessageAttributes": {}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see above, it contains `Message` field with `StackId`. Thus when your function gets this message from SNS, you have to parse it to get the `StackId`, and then use AWS SDK to [describe-stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/describe-stacks.html). The outcome of the SDK call will contain the stack's outputs.